# Smoothing of graph gives a huge difference in the range

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot a smooth curve using the x,y cordinates above. Howsoever the graph which i get is out of the range of my data. The snippet of my code is here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import spline

ylist = [0.36758563074352546, 0.27634194831013914, 0.22261484098939929, 0.10891089108910891, 0.31578947368421051, 0.086956521739130432, 0.27272727272727271, 0.18181818181818182, 0.0, 0.0, 0.92000000000000004, 0.0, 0.10526315789473684, 0.23333333333333334]
xlist = [0.025000000000000001, 0.075000000000000011, 0.125, 0.17500000000000002, 0.22500000000000001, 0.27500000000000002, 0.32500000000000001, 0.375, 0.42500000000000004, 0.47500000000000003, 0.52500000000000002, 0.57500000000000007, 0.625, 0.97500000000000009]

xlist_smooth = np.linspace(xlist.min(), xlist.max(), 100)
ylist_smooth = spline(xlist, ylist, xlist_smooth)
plt.plot(xlist_smooth,ylist_smooth)
```

I get the following curve as the output[image: plot_example]

Comment: You should include your `import` statements for us to be able to help you better. Where does the `spline` function come from?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you plotted your input x and y data on the same axes. From the looks of it, it seems that you are doing cubic spline interpolation rather than smoothing (i.e. your 'smooth' output passes through all of your input data points), and your interpolant is overshooting around x=0.8.

Comment: voting to close: without knowing the origin of `spline` it's impossible to answer this question.  OP was asked and has not answered.

Comment: These are the import statements used by me.  
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.interpolate import spline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that spline interpolation of a higher order is not suitable for smoothing your data.

Below I plotted spline interpolations of order 0 to 3. What you see is that once you demand continuity of the derivative (order 2 and higher) you run into problems with the last two points.

I guess choosing a spline interpolation is not a good choice here. Interpolation assumes that there are no measurement errors and you seem to have a clear outlier in your data.

Depending on what you want to do here, fitting a piecewise continuous spline (order=1) may be fine for you. Otherwise you probably have to look for a different smoothing strategy.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ylist = [0.36758563074352546, 0.27634194831013914, 0.22261484098939929,
         0.10891089108910891, 0.31578947368421051, 0.086956521739130432, 
         0.27272727272727271, 0.18181818181818182, 0.0, 0.0,
         0.92000000000000004, 0.0, 0.10526315789473684, 0.23333333333333334]
xlist = [0.025000000000000001, 0.075000000000000011, 0.125, 0.17500000000000002,
         0.22500000000000001, 0.27500000000000002, 0.32500000000000001, 0.375,
         0.42500000000000004, 0.47500000000000003, 0.52500000000000002, 
         0.57500000000000007, 0.625, 0.97500000000000009]

xlist_smooth = np.linspace(min(xlist), max(xlist), 100)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,1, sharex=True)
for order, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ylist_smooth = spline(xlist, ylist, xlist_smooth, order=order)
    ax.plot(xlist_smooth, ylist_smooth,  label="spline order %s" % order)
    ax.scatter(xlist, ylist, label="knots")
    ax.set_ylim(min(xlist)-1,max(xlist)+1)
    ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Also, though, there are approaches that are both smooth, go through all the points, and don't show the crazy bump at the end.

Comment: @tom10, I would be very interested in seeing a smooth interpolation that handles this particular case better.

Comment: Because the OP is unclear about the criteria for a good answer, and the title of the question is misdirecting the reader to the goal of "smoothing", any additional answer is unlikely to be accepted or be of use to anyone else in the future. I don't really want to go through the process of writing a new answer, then, essentially just for you. Maybe ask a similar question that's accurately worded, if you want to go through the trouble.  But there are a number of interpolation methods that don't go crazy every time there's a gap in the data, which I just wanted to note for other readers.

Comment: @tom10, yes I totally understand that preparing another answer may not be worth it. But if you have some time to share your ideas or alternatives in the comments, I would be very grateful!

Comment: I answered a different question (and without all the problems I mention in my previous comment) where I think the answer also addresses the question you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221444/intuitive-interpolation-between-unevenly-spaced-points/31222380#31222380