# scipy: interpolation, cubic & linear

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate my set of data (first columnt is the time, third columnt is the actual data):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=" ")

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 2]

xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
y_smooth = interp1d(x, y)(xx)
#y_smooth = interp1d(x, y, kind="cubic")(xx)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(xx, y_smooth, "r-")

plt.show()
```

but I see some strange difference between linear and cubic interpolation.
Here is the result for linear:
[image]

Here is the same for cubic:
[image]

I'm not sure, why is graph jumping all the time and `y_smooth` contains incorrect values?

```
ipdb> y_smooth_linear.max()
141.5481144
ipdb> y_smooth_cubic.max()
1.2663431888584225e+18
```

Can anybody explain to me, how can I change my code to achieve correct interpolation?

*UPD*: here is [`data.cvs` file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gds2ny10tbg0ixq/data.csv?dl=1)

Comment: probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569431/smoothing-of-graph-gives-a-huge-difference-in-the-range/30588890#30588890

Comment: @rth I've added link to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data contains several y values for the same x value. This violates the assumptions of most interpolation algorithms.

Either discard the rows with duplicate x values, average the y values for each individual x, or obtain a better resolution for the x values such that they aren't the same anymore.

Comment: also see this [scipy issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2638), `scipy.interpolate.splmake` appears to be the only interpolation routine in `scipy` that supports it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Given [cfh's observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914311/190597) that `x` has duplicate values, you could use `np.unique`
to select a unique value of `y` for each `x`:

```
x2, idx = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
y2 = y[idx]
```

`return_index=True` causes [np.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to return not only the unique values, `x2`, but also the locations, `idx`, of the unique `x`s in the original `x` array. Note that this selects the *first* value of `y` for each unique `x`.

If you'd like to average all the `y` values for each unique `x`, you could use
[stats.binned_statistic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html):

```
import scipy.stats as stats
x2, inv = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
y2, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
    x=inv, values=y, statistic='mean', bins=inv.max()+1)
```

`return_inverse=True` tells `np.unique` to return indices from which the
original array can be reconstructed. Those indices can also serve as categorical
labels or "factors", which is how they are being used in the call to
`binned_statistic` above.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import scipy.stats as stats

data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=" ")

x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

x2, idx, inv = np.unique(x, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
y_uniq = y[idx]
y_ave, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
    x=inv, values=y, statistic='mean', bins=inv.max()+1)

xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
y_smooth = interp1d(x, y)(xx)
y_smooth2 = interp1d(x2, y_uniq, kind="cubic")(xx)
y_smooth3 = interp1d(x2, y_ave, kind="cubic")(xx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(xx, y_smooth, "r-", label='linear')
ax[1].plot(xx, y_smooth2, "b-", label='cubic (first y)')
ax[2].plot(xx, y_smooth3, "b-", label='cubic (ave y)')
ax[0].legend(loc='best')
ax[1].legend(loc='best')
ax[2].legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]