# Intuitive interpolation between unevenly spaced points

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have the following graph that I want to digitize to a high-quality publication grade figure using Python and Matplotlib:

[image]

I used a digitizer program to grab a few samples from one of the 3 data sets:

```
x_data = np.array([
1,
1.2371,
1.6809,
2.89151,
5.13304,
9.23238,
])

y_data = np.array([
0.0688824,
0.0490012,
0.0332843,
0.0235889,
0.0222304,
0.0245952,
])
```

I have already tried 3 different methods of fitting a curve through these data points. The first method being to draw a spline through the points using `scipy.interpolate import spline`

This results in (with the actual data points drawn as blue markers):

[image]

This is obvisously no good.

My second attempt was to draw a curve fit using a series of different order polinimials using `scipy.optimize import curve_fit`. Even up to a fourth order polynomial the answer is useless (the lower order ones were even more useless):

[image]

Finally, I used `scipy.interpolate import interp1d` to try and interpolate between the data points. Linear interpolation obviously yields expected results but the line are straight and the whole purpose of this exercise is to get a nice smooth curve:

[image]

If I then use cubic interpolation I get a rubish result, however quadratic interpolation yields a slightly better result:

[image]

But it's not quite there yet, and I don't think `interp1d` can do higher order interpolation.

Is there anyone out there who has a good method of doing this? Maybe I would be better off trying to do it in IPE or something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A standard cubic spline is not very good at reasonable looking interpolations between data points that are very unevenly spaced.  Fortunately, there are plenty of other interpolation algorithms and [Scipy provides a number of them](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/interpolate.html).  Here are a few applied to your data:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline, UnivariateSpline, Akima1DInterpolator, PchipInterpolator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.array([1, 1.2371, 1.6809, 2.89151, 5.13304, 9.23238])

y_data = np.array([0.0688824, 0.0490012, 0.0332843, 0.0235889, 0.0222304, 0.0245952])

x_data_smooth = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

spl = UnivariateSpline(x_data, y_data, s=0, k=2)
y_data_smooth = spl(x_data_smooth)
ax.plot(x_data_smooth, y_data_smooth, 'b')

bi = Akima1DInterpolator(x_data, y_data)
y_data_smooth = bi(x_data_smooth)
ax.plot(x_data_smooth, y_data_smooth, 'g')

bi = PchipInterpolator(x_data, y_data)
y_data_smooth = bi(x_data_smooth)
ax.plot(x_data_smooth, y_data_smooth, 'k')

ax.plot(x_data_smooth, y_data_smooth)
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data)

plt.show()
```

I suggest looking through these, and also a few others, and finding one that matches what you think looks right.  Also, though, you may want to sample a few more points.  For example, I think the PCHIP algorithm wants to keep the fit monotonic between data points, so digitizing your minimum point would be useful (and probably a good idea regardless of the algorithm you use).

Comment: Thank you @tom10 for the thorough answer! I will certainly take a look and all the fits you did looks sufficiently good for my purposes!