# Construct a smooth curve from mouse coordinates

Tags: python, curve, points, smoothing

In a project I'm working on, i get mouse coordinates every X milliseconds. I would like to draw the most likely path between these coordinates.

By example : 
- After X ms, i could get these (x,y) coordinates : (0, 0), (3, 1), (5, 4), (6, 7)
- After 2*X ms i could have this : (0, 0), (3, 1), (5, 4), (6, 7), (8, 5), (11, -7)
- etc.

I would like to draw step by step a path between these points, once I've drawn a path i can't change it (i can't wait to have all the coordinates to draw the line).

I started to think about a solution where I draw lines between pair of coordinates by calculating a polynomial fit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def construct_path(points):
    x = points[:,0]
    y = points[:,1]

    (x_new,y_new) = ([],[])
    for i in range(0,len(x) - 2):
        (x_tmp, y_tmp) =  get_new_points(x[i:(i+3)], y[i:(i+3)], (i+3) == len(x))
        (x_new,y_new) = (x_new + x_tmp.tolist(), y_new + y_tmp.tolist())
        previous_points = [x_tmp,y_tmp]

    return (x_new, y_new)

def get_new_points(x,y, end):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)

    # calculate polynomial
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
    f = np.poly1d(z)

    # calculate new x's and y's

    if not end:
        x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[1], 11)
    else:
        x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[1], 10, endpoint=False).tolist() + np.linspace(x[1], x[2], 11).tolist()
        x_new = np.array(x_new)
    y_new = f(x_new)

    print(x_new, y_new)
    return (x_new, y_new)


points = np.array([(0, 0), (3, 1), (5, 4), (6, 7), (8, 5), (11, -7) ])

x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]
(x_new, y_new) = construct_path(points)

plt.plot(x,y,'o',np.array(x_new),np.array(y_new))
plt.xlim([-2, 12])
plt.ylim([-10, 10])
plt.show()
```

The result is ok :
[image: smooth curve]

But it doesn't work when points have close x's or y's (ex : (0, 0), (3, 1), (5.8, 4), (6, 7), (8, 5), (11, -7))

[image: smooth_curve2]

EDIT : found some interesting leads :

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

def range_spline(x,y):
    t = np.arange(x.shape[0], dtype=float)
    t /= t[-1]
    nt = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
    new_x = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, x, nt)
    new_y = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, y, nt)
    return (new_x,new_y)

def dist_spline(x,y):
    t = np.zeros(x.shape)
    t[1:] = np.sqrt((x[1:] - x[:-1])**2 + (y[1:] - y[:-1])**2)
    t = np.cumsum(t)
    t /= t[-1]
    nt = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
    new_x = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, x, nt)
    new_y = scipy.interpolate.spline(t, y, nt)
    return (new_x, new_y)

x = np.array([ 0,  3,  6,  6,  8,  11, 8, 6, 6])
y = np.array([ 0,  1,  4,  7,  5,  -7, -10, -10, -5])
#x = np.array([ 0, 2, 4])
#y = np.array([ 0, 2, 0])


(x1, y1) = range_spline(x,y)
(x2,y2) = dist_spline(x,y)

plt.plot(x,y, 'o')
plt.plot(x1, y1, label='range_spline')
plt.plot(x2, y2, label='dist_spline')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

It works well when there are many points :
[image: splines]

But not so well when there are less than 5 points (which is what i'd like) :
[image]

Comment: You could try some piecewise-monotonic interpolation method like [PCHIP](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator). ```The interpolator preserves monotonicity in the interpolation data and does not overshoot if the data is not smooth.```

Comment: You would benefit by using a spline rather than polynomial fits since the spline will also match derivatives at the boundaries between sections.  [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221444/intuitive-interpolation-between-unevenly-spaced-points) where I compared different spline methods (including pchip), and I think the same approach could be used here.