# Hot to sketch a curve and convert it to numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am in a real need of a tool that does the following:

You draw with your mouse a curve from a starting point to a finish point and then it exports this to an object, which can then be interpolated as a `numpy` array to a given number of points.

Is anybody aware of such tool, or a way to achieve something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Not really a question for stackoverflow

Comment: Cool question, but not really ideal for Stack Overflow. You can interpolate like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222380/2836621 and make points like this (similar thing perfectly achievable with Python too)... https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297587/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started. Draw your curve with **Photoshop**, **GIMP** or your favourite painting/drawing program and save it as a white line on a black background in PNG/GIF/JPEG/TIFF format, or any other format that [PIL/Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) understands:

[image]

Load the image with **PIL/Pillow**, blur it a little to allow for discontinuities in your hand-drawn-curve, then find the brightest pixel in each column. Save as a ".npy" file that you can load and interpolate to any dimension of array you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

# Check an image file was supplied
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: curve2array IMAGE", file=sys.stderr)
    exit(1)

# Assign filename and open image as greyscale
filename = sys.argv[1]
im = Image.open(filename).convert('L')

# OPTIONAL = Blur the image a little to allow discontinuities in hand-sketched curves
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(1))

# Convert image to Numpy array and get row number of brightest pixel in each column
na    = np.array(im)
yvals = np.argmax(im, axis=0)
yvals = na.shape[0] - yvals         # Make origin at bottom-left instead of top-left

# Write result as ".npy" file
np.save('result.npy', yvals)
```

My input image is 600px wide by 400 pixels tall, so there are 600 y-values and the last is the largest one at 394 because it's near the top of a 400 px high image. The array looks like this:

```
array([  1,   1,   3,   6,  10,  13,  16,  20,  23,  26,  29,  32,  36,
        39,  42,  45,  48,  51,  54,  57,  59,  62,  65,  68,  71,  74,
        76,  79,  82,  84,  87,  90,  92,  95,  97, 100, 102, 104, 107,
       109, 111, 114, 116, 118, 120, 123, 125, 127, 129, 131, 133, 135,
       137, 139, 140, 142, 144, 146, 148, 149, 151, 153, 154, 156, 157,
       159, 160, 162, 163, 164, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 172, 173, 174,
       175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 180, 181, 182, 182, 183, 184, 184,
       185, 185, 186, 186, 187, 187, 187, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 188,
       188, 188, 188, 188, 188, 187, 187, 187, 186, 186, 185, 185, 184,
       184, 183, 182, 181, 180, 180, 179, 178, 177, 176, 175, 173, 172,
       171, 170, 169, 167, 166, 165, 163, 162, 160, 159, 157, 156, 155,
       153, 152, 150, 149, 147, 145, 144, 142, 141, 139, 138, 136, 135,
       133, 132, 130, 129, 127, 126, 124, 123, 121, 120, 119, 117, 116,
       114, 113, 112, 110, 109, 108, 106, 105, 104, 103, 101, 100,  99,
        98,  97,  96,  95,  94,  92,  91,  90,  89,  88,  87,  86,  85,
        85,  84,  83,  82,  81,  80,  79,  79,  78,  77,  76,  75,  75,
        74,  73,  72,  72,  71,  70,  70,  69,  68,  68,  67,  66,  66,
        65,  64,  64,  63,  63,  62,  61,  61,  60,  60,  59,  58,  58,
        57,  57,  56,  56,  55,  55,  54,  54,  53,  53,  52,  52,  51,
        51,  50,  50,  49,  49,  48,  48,  47,  47,  47,  46,  46,  45,
        45,  45,  44,  44,  43,  43,  43,  42,  42,  42,  41,  41,  41,
        40,  40,  40,  39,  39,  39,  38,  38,  38,  38,  37,  37,  37,
        37,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,  34,  34,
        34,  34,  34,  34,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,
        33,  33,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  32,
        32,  32,  32,  32,  32,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,  33,
        33,  33,  34,  34,  34,  34,  34,  34,  35,  35,  35,  35,  35,
        36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  37,  37,  37,  37,  38,  38,  38,  39,
        39,  39,  40,  40,  40,  41,  41,  41,  42,  42,  42,  43,  43,
        43,  44,  44,  45,  45,  46,  46,  46,  47,  47,  48,  48,  49,
        49,  50,  50,  51,  51,  52,  52,  53,  53,  54,  55,  55,  56,
        56,  57,  57,  58,  59,  59,  60,  60,  61,  62,  62,  63,  64,
        64,  65,  66,  66,  67,  68,  69,  69,  70,  71,  72,  72,  73,
        74,  75,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,
        85,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,
        97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,
       110, 111, 112, 113, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 123, 124,
       125, 126, 128, 129, 130, 131, 133, 134, 135, 136, 138, 139, 140,
       142, 143, 145, 146, 147, 149, 150, 152, 153, 155, 156, 157, 159,
       160, 162, 163, 165, 167, 168, 170, 171, 173, 175, 176, 178, 179,
       181, 183, 185, 186, 188, 190, 192, 193, 195, 197, 199, 201, 203,
       204, 206, 208, 210, 212, 214, 216, 218, 220, 222, 224, 226, 229,
       231, 233, 235, 237, 239, 242, 244, 246, 248, 251, 253, 256, 258,
       261, 263, 266, 268, 271, 273, 276, 279, 281, 284, 287, 290, 292,
       295, 298, 301, 304, 307, 310, 314, 317, 320, 323, 327, 330, 334,
       337, 341, 344, 348, 352, 356, 360, 364, 368, 372, 376, 381, 385,
       390, 394])
```

I saved the script above as `curve2array`, so I run it with:

```
./curve2array image.png
```